# How to add SQLiteOpenFlags.FullMutex flag in Xamarin iOS SQLite

Tags: c#, multithreading, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to use a SQLite database in my project accross multiple threads [using a method discussed](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/549/sqlite-net-and-multiple-threads) in the Xamarin forums. Within it they create the following static class:

```
public static class Data {
    static readonly string Path = System.IO.Path.Combine (Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "database.db");
    static SQLite.SQLiteConnection connection;
    public static SQLite.SQLiteConnection Connection
    {
        get {
            if (connection == null) {
                connection = new SQLiteConnection (Path,SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | SQLiteOpenFlags.Create | SQLiteOpenFlags.FullMutex , true);
            }
            return connection;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to implement this however the connection method I am currently using has a different method signature. I think this is because I'm using PCL. I currently connect using:

```
SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection (new SQLitePlatformIOS (), AppController._dbPath, false, null);
```

How do I add `SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | SQLiteOpenFlags.Create | SQLiteOpenFlags.FullMutex` so I can use the connection like:

```
new SQLiteConnection (Path,SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | SQLiteOpenFlags.Create | SQLiteOpenFlags.FullMutex , true)
```

I've tired the following but it's failing as it's not matching the required method signature

```
_connection = new SQLiteConnection (new SQLitePlatformIOS (),Path,false,null,SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite | SQLiteOpenFlags.Create | SQLiteOpenFlags.FullMutex);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also using SQLite in my PCL project and I have the following method which is what you are trying to find.

```
public SQLiteConnection(ISQLitePlatform sqlitePlatform
                        , string databasePath
                        , SQLiteOpenFlags openFlags
                        , bool storeDateTimeAsTicks = true
                        , IBlobSerializer serializer = null
                        , IDictionary<string, TableMapping> tableMappings = null
                        , IDictionary<Type, string> extraTypeMappings = null
                        , IContractResolver resolver = null);
```

The PCL SQLite version I am using is 3.0.5, you can find the Nuget [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net-PCL). 
If interested you can get the `Async` version [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net.Async-PCL/).